# OpenCV face detection can not find any

Tags: java, opencv, face-detection

I have followed online tutorials and managed to write a simple class like this:

```
public class FaceDetector
{

    public static void detect(String imageFile) {

        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        System.out.println("\nRunning FaceDetector");

        CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(FaceDetector.class.getResource("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml").getPath());
        Mat image = Highgui.imread(imageFile);

        MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);

        int faceCount = faceDetections.toArray().length;
        System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s faces", faceCount));

        for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
            Core.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
                    new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
        }

        String filename = imageFile+"_output.png";
        System.out.println(String.format("Writing %s", filename));
        Highgui.imwrite(filename, image);
    }
}
```

However I have tried this with over 200 profile pictures and it could not detect a single one. Since it rewrites the image file untouched, I know it reads image correctly. It is not giving any errors so. What should I do now? Any redirections? Where should I read? what am I missing?

Comment: try : `faceDetector.isOpened()` to see if it found the cascade at all

Comment: Note: I have also tried haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml as classifier

Comment: Thanks it worked. In case for someone having similar problem; I have moved xmls under a folder name classifier and created faceDetector like this:
        
CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier();        faceDetector.load("classifier/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");

Comment: again, don't use a frontalface cascade with profile images. try lbpcascade_profileface.xml or similar

Answer (score 3):

Profile faces are very hard to find with the standard opencv face detector, especially if you use the default haardcascade_frontalface classifiers.

Basically, the Viola-Jones algorithm that opencv uses have to be trained with positive and negative examples, hence the differences in the xml files. Those with the **frontalface** are trained using frontal images and have a good detection rate around +/- 30° from the frontal pose. For steeper poses you should probably try and use a different classifier: [here](http://alereimondo.no-ip.org/OpenCV/34) you can find a pretty good selection. You'll notice that opencv "face detector" is indeed just an object detector tuned for faces.

You can also try to train your own adaboost cascade for face detection, there are several tutorials but i haven't had much success in that.

**So, to summarize the answer**: low detection rate in profile faces with standard opencv face detector is quite common, there is not much you can do about it expect trying to change the cascade classifier.

Hope this helps..